# Linearity of expectations

Tags: probability, probability-theory

You play a new online game called, "Pokey Mango!" It's a game where you go around collecting strange cartoonish beasts.

Suppose there are only three such beasts in the game, and each beast has the following probability of being found:

Snorlax( 1/6 )

Drowzee (1/3)

Magikarp (1/2)

The expected total number of beasts you need to collect before you have collected them all (In this case there are 3 only )  ?

P.S. I'm facing difficulties while solving any linearity of expectations problem. It'd be great if you could point me towards some sources which have more questions like this which would help me in clearing my doubts.

Comment: The general category of problems goes by the name ["coupon collector's problems"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem).

Comment: Try expressing P({finished at time k}) = $\sum_{i=1}^3$ P({collected species up to time k-1 include two species but not i})*P({collect species i at time k}).

Comment: I got a solution of this problem but I'm unable to understand the relations between different expectations. Can you please explain your approach and post it as an answer ?